# Cannot find index.html file in existing website files

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I had purchased a Wordpress web template and a designer worked on it and then uploaded it to the site.

The site needs to be modified and I figured I could do it myself. I downloaded all the files uploaded but cannot find any folders containing the index.html file.

I see a index.php file in every folder. What folder do I pull up to edit in order to change details on the homepage of the website?

Comment: If the site is written in PHP, then 'index.php' will essentially be the equivalent of 'index.html'

Comment: thank you, I was assuming the same too. However, when I pull up index.php into the text editor it does not contain the homepage information , except a reference to additional php scripts.

Comment: No problem.. Just look for the files being referenced to find the actual page content

Answer (score 1):

index.php has equivalent functionality to index.html, except that it can contain PHP script. Look in those files. It will contain the HTML you are looking for.

Comment: I was assuming index.php was the file but when I opened it in brackets it doesnt show any of the content. I've dug through all files and each folder appears to contain the index.php file. Is there any specific folder which has the relevant index.php file which has the content for the homepage?

Comment: The homepage should be in the root folder of the website, so the top directory you downloaded the template to, or typically public_html or /var/www/ on an Apache server.

Comment: Check in the folder containing your Theme or Template that you bought

Comment: im not sure if I even did this correctly, but i logged into the FTP and viewed all the files. I then downloaded the entire folder under the website directory onto my hdd. I believe I should have all the files necessary for the site the function properly. How do I find the root folder for the website?

Comment: I would recommend using Sublime Text Editor. This editor contains a nifty little Search tool (CTRL+SHIFT+F) to conduct a entire folder/files search based on keywords. You could search for a class name found only on the homepage. It would save you a lot of time

Comment: From the home directories index.php folder, when I open it in text editor it says this: <?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

Comment: IndieRok, Thank you! I will download sublime text editor. I am currently using Brackets.

Comment: From that, I can tell you that your header file HTML is in that wp-blog-header.php file.

Comment: Maybe understanding Wordpress' folders structure could be helpful too: http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-internal-function/

Comment: All the files you are looking for to edit your pages are always (most the time) located in the "/wp-content/themes" folder.

Comment: jeez thanks so much guys. I know I have a long way to go. I am just starting out w/ really making sites from templates. I am trying to search using sublime I am also checking the wp-blog-header.php file now!